# How to rotate the output image from the camera?

Tags: ios, swift, vlc

I have a streaming application. I need to rotate the device, the image does not rotate rotated. How can I rotate the image coming out of the camera?

It’s not suitable for me to flip only UIView because the viewer’s image is not turned correctly.
I use [vlc](https://github.com/videolan/vlckit)

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends on how you are accessing `vlc` but given that `vlc` has a `video-filter=rotate` option, coupled with its `rotate-angle` setting, there must be a way for you to set those options from within your code.
Even if you are only performing a direct call on the command line:

```
vlc --video-filter=rotate --rotate-angle=270.0 myvideo.mp4
```

Will work.